# How to block <b> or <i> in a comment box using a regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I been trying to block some word such as `<b>` or `<i>` for a project

```
        Regex regExp = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z_]*$");   


        if (regExp.IsMatch(status.ToString()))
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Comment added successfully.";
            lblStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        }
        else
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Comment failed to add!!!.";
            lblStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
```

this is the code that i write but somehow it is not able to block
is my code wrong? i just want to show an error when it was press submit( this is a comment box which have a button to submit. i just want to show me else statement not giving me the error page)

Comment: What are you trying to match exactly?

Comment: actually i trying to block comment if the user enter <b> or <i> or just some random symbol. i have type just some symbol such as %^&* and it was able to submit. I want to just accept words and number not just all symbol

Answer (score 1):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$
```

That will match only numbers, letters and spaces. You are going to have to determine based on your particular case if periods, commmas, semicolons and the like are acceptable. Keep in mind that extremely constrictive rules can be annoying for users, and it may be best to strip out any unwanted characters on the server-side.

---

Update:

You can create a negation group like this [^] where any characters following the caret will not be allowed. See codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial which is a great article on regexes.

Comment: oh i see. Thank you very much but i would like to know what will be the code like if i want to exclude the like of @,#,*,+,- as they are not alphanumeric?

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you very much. I would like to know what will be the code like if i want to filter out ($+-*^) and state that the comment cannot be add.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank You very much. I would like know if want to just filter these few out(&,-,+,*,$) and show the comment cannot be add(fall in the else part of my code)

Comment: sorry for the spamming of reply as i was trying to type shift enter and it auto add the comment

Comment: You can create a negation group like this `[^]` where any characters following the caret will not be allowed. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial which is a great article on regexes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help once again. It really help me a lot.

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider marking it as the answer if it indeed did answer your question :)

Comment: after my finding of the coding i wrote the code in these way 
[code]^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\\/(),_\s]+$ but it give me error saying that unrecognized unknown sequence so i would like to know where did my code go wrong?

Comment: I think that perhaps `\-` is an invalid escape sequence. You may not need the preceeding backslash.

Comment: i know i might be nuisance but when i try to add in my comment with just @# it still able to add in. It does not show me the comment fail to add in. I have remove the `\-` but it seem my code not working at all

Comment: `^.*[^@#]$` will allow any string not containing "@" and "#". This is a "blacklist" approach. If you want a "whitelist" approach then use what I suggested in my answer which only *allows* certain characters.

Comment: once again thanks for your help. Now I have solve my problem with your code earlier. Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure! Please consider marking my answer as the accepted answer if it helped you out sufficiently :).